# Installing a Apache server on dedicated hosting

Tags: linux, apache, server, ubuntu-14.04, dedicated-server

I have recently bought a dedicated server through a vendor. Now i want to install a Apache server like WAMP or easyPHP in this dedicated server remotely. How do I do this using SSH.

The dedicated server has UBUNTU server installed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apt-get` package installer to install apache.  Type:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This will install apache for you.

You can use

```
service apache2 start
```

to start the apache.  This may require `sudo` like so: `sudo service apache2 start`.

You can find a lot of information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Depending on your host you may have the option to install ready-to-install images for you with the full LAMP stack so that you don't have to go through this process manually.  I'd check that too.

Comment: Thanks you Its a great help. Can I ask you one off topic question. At the moment i can only use SSH to get to my dedicated server. How can i remotely view (install the gnome on server?) ? Is there any tools that i can use to remotely access the server using a graphical user interface, because its very time consuming to ssh everytime.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  You typically only have access through ssh and trying to install gnome would disconnect you anyway.

Comment: Usually vncserver is available for remote viewing of the desktop. If the ports are open you can contact it directly, or if not, setup a vnc tunnel using ssh.

Comment: It's possible to use virtual X sessions on remote servers, using vnc4server for example. vnc4server is available on Ubuntu